# exec store procedure with parameter date format getting error

Tags: php, sql-server, parameter-passing, slim

I am using slim framework to get API with parameter date. It's getting error when I am using date format 'yyyy-mm-dd'.

This is the code :

```
 $time = strtotime('07/16/2020');
 $newDate = date('Y-m-d',$time);    
 $Poli    = $args['poli'];
 $sql = "Exec Proc_JKN_Rekap @Tgl=$newDate, @Poli= $Poli";
```

Error :

> **Message:** SQLSTATE[42000]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect
>       syntax near '-'.

Answer (score 0):

this should be more reliable

```
// $inputDateString is whatever your function receives as date
$date = \DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $inputDateString);

// validate the date
// if the input date is invalid the comparison will fail
// this works even for dates like February 31st
if ( $date->format('d/m/Y') !== $inputDateString ) {
     throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Invalid date string: '.inputDateString);
}


$dateString = $date->format('Y-m-d');

$Poli = $args['poli'];
$sql  = "Exec Proc_JKN_Rekap @Tgl=$newDate, @Poli= $Poli";
```